# installing gazebo from dev branch

Tags: gazebo, installation

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Today I tried to install gazebo from the dev branch, and it fails at the compile stage because it can't find urdf related files.  So do I now have to install the ROS system to get Gazebo working?  How do I proceed?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13/installing-gazebo-from-dev-branch/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem has been fixed in the dev branch. Update and you will be fine.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0